# Do I need Windows Server 2012 and VS 2012 or 2013 to write plugins for MS CRM 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm, windows-server-2008-r2, dynamics-crm-2015

I've been asked to take a look at some of our current plugins and alter them for our upgrade to 2015. However, looking at the SDK it says the system requirements (see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44567)) are Windows Server 2012 (and 8, but not relevant for me) and Visual Studio 2012 or 2013.

I'm currently on Windows Server 2008 R2 and using Visual Studio 2010. So can I still develop the plugins for 2015 or do I need to upgrade? Surely from my point of view it's just referencing a new dll?

***UPDATE***

Thanks to Guido for the answer, which is true. However, for anyone reading this I would recommend checking what the latest version of the CRM SDK Developer Kit is. At the time of writing this the latest version is the CRM 2013 version and is compatible with VS 2012 only, though a hack (found [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/tsgrdcrmblog/archive/2014/08/23/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-toolkit-with-visual-studio-2013)) can be used to try and get CRM 2013 Developer Kit to work in VS 2013. I've opted for the route of installing VS 2012 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least Visual Studio 2012 to write plugins compatible with CRM 2015.

If you use CRM 2015 SDK dlls, the target of your project should be .NET 4.5.2

Comment: But I don't need Windows Server 2012? What is this requirement for with regards to the SDK then?

Comment: To clarify @GuidoPreite's answer, you can build the plugin using a machine running at least VS 2012. The server version requirement comes from running CRM, not Visual Studio.

Comment: I have Net 4.5.2, in Windows 2012 R2, and CRM 2016 installed. I use VS 2013. I want créate WCF Services .NET 4.6.1, and hosting in IIS 8.5 in the  Windows 2012 R2 + CRM 2016 server.
CRM 2016 manages Net 4.5.2. Any problems if I install  Targeting Pack .NET Framework 4.6.1 ?

Comment: ***HOW-TO  write plugins compatible with CRM 2016?*** _VS 2013_, _VS 2012_ ? *.NET 4.5.2* ?

Comment: @Kiquenet for CRM 2016 the important is that you target .NET 4.5.2